# How to use PyDrive Authentication with an oAuth Access Token directly?

Tags: python, oauth, google-drive-api, pydrive

I'm building a web app, where a user select a file from his drive using Google Picker API, but I want to get the full public link for the selected document, I already have an access token which I got on the frontend with JS and and the Google APIs, I want now to send it to the server (I already know that this is a bad practice, but this app is private and only some friends will use it) .

The docs of PyDrive says that you need the user to surf to some generated URL by pydrive get the access code and enter it, is there a way to authenticate with pydrive just through the access token I already have ?

Comment: If this information was not useful for you, I'm sorry. http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html#building-your-own-authentication-flow

Comment: were you able to achieve this?

Comment: @charsi I ended up getting a token from my user then sending to the server, where I use it to generate a credential JSON object to use with Pydrive . the link provided by the first comment was helpful